# How can i achieve autofill feature while email is already exist in database or API In angular 12

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, angular12

If the email is existed in database, then all the required input field get autofill How I can achieve this feature in angular with using API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using forms, you can implement that by

`this.formName.formControlName.setValue(valueYouWantToSet);`

for this to work, you will have to get the controls of the form via:

`get f() { return this.formName.controls }`

If you are not using forms and want to implement via ngModel(`[(ngModel)]="variableName"`), then you can try with

`this.variableName = valueYouWantToSet`